# Getting the <ul> <li> and <b> tags in htmlAgilityPack VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I honestly don't know how to do this, and I am very stuck. My code is probably not worth sharing, but I will try my best to ask the question.

```
<div class="pricing-table">
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="plan">
            <h3>PPTP <span>$0</span></h3>
            <ul>
                <li><b>IP:</b> " (hidden)"</li>
                <li><b>Username:</b> " Guest"</li>
                <li><b>Password:</b> " (hidden)"</li>
                <li><b>Unlimited</b> " Bandwidth"</li>
                <li><b>Torrents</b> " Allowed"</li>
                <li><b>No</b> " Logging"</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(This is the second one)

```
<div class="span4">
    <div class="plan most-popular">
        <h3>Open<span>$0</span></h3>
        <div class="plan-ribbon-wrapper">
            <div class="plan-ribbon">
                Popular
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><b>Username:</b> user</li>
            <li><b>Password:</b> (hidden)</li>
            <li><b>TCP</b> 80, 443</li>
            <li><b>UDP</b> 53, 40000</li>
            <li><b>Unlimited</b> Bandwidth</li>
            <li><b>Torrents</b> Allowed</li>
            <li><b>No</b> Logging</li>
        </ul><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href=
        "%20(hidden)">Download</a>
    </div>
</div>
<ul>
    <li><b>Username:</b> user</li>
    <li><b>Password:</b> (hidden)</li>
    <li><b>TCP</b> 80, 443</li>
    <li><b>UDP</b> 53, 40000</li>
    <li><b>Unlimited</b> Bandwidth</li>
    <li><b>Torrents</b> Allowed</li>
    <li><b>No</b> Logging</li>
</ul>
```

Using this HTML code, I want to copy the username and password and put it into a label on my form.

Here is my code

```
Imports HtmlAgilityPack
Public Class Form1
Dim Prev_Pass, Prev_User, Currt_Pass, Currt_User, Info
Dim counter As Integer
Dim web As New HtmlWeb()
Dim htmldoc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
Dim htmlnodes As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection = Nothing
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    htmldoc = web.Load("website")
    htmlnodes = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class=""pricing-table""]")
    For Each node As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In htmlnodes
        Dim releaseNode = node.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class=""plan most-popular""]")
            Info = releaseNode.SelectSingleNode("//ul/li/b[contains(text(), 'Username: ')]").InnerText
    Next
    Label3.Text = Info
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: please include the *full* HTML excerpt.

Comment: <div class="span4"> <div class="plan most-popular"> <h3>Open<span>$0</span></h3> <div class="plan-ribbon-wrapper"><div class="plan-ribbon">Popular</div></div> <ul> <li><b>Username:</b> user</li> <li><b>Password:</b> N7yh6H</li> <li><b>TCP</b> 80, 443</li> <li><b>UDP</b> 53, 40000</li> <li><b>Unlimited</b> Bandwidth</li> <li><b>Torrents</b> Allowed</li> <li><b>No</b> Logging</li> </ul> <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="(hidden link)">Download</a> </div> </div>

Comment: Thanks bud. I wrote some code for you against the isolated segment that you provided in your first revision of the question. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Here let me update the entire HTML code with both tables so you can make an edit of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following annotations:

```
<li>
    <b>Username:</b> <!-- Use XPath to obtain this element. -->
    " user" <!-- This is the next sibling. -->
</li>
```

With these annotations in mind:

You can obtain the `<b>` element using XPath as you have done already and then access the username or password text by means of the `NextSibling` property like so:

```
Dim username = 
    htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(
        "//ul/li/b[text()='Username:']").NextSibling.InnerHtml

Dim password =
    htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(
        "//ul/li/b[text()='Password:']").NextSibling.InnerHtml
```

If you want to access the second occurrence of the element instead of the first, then you you should either use a more specific XPath or use  `SelectNodes` and obtain the element located at the second index by means of an *indexer* like this:

```
Dim username =
    htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
        "//ul/li/b[text()='Username:']")(1).NextSibling.InnerHtml
```

Comment: That worked but let me update my question because there are two different tables on this website that have Username in them and when I do this, it finds the first thing on the website that has Username in it. This first username is not the one I want.

Comment: @Neckup4 Updated my answer. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Didn't consider the InnerHtml rather the InnerText. I'm away from my computer at the  moment will have to test that when I return.

Comment: @Neckup4 Alright. I'm going to bed, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks for your help. I'll be sure to reference you in my referrals section of the code. Haha.